# Is there a way to find out the values ​of 4 cells are the same or different in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, equals

I found something confusing in Microsoft Excel.
I fill Cell A1, A2, A3, A4 with the same number 1,
then I enter the formula **= A1 = A2 = A3 = A4** on **cell A5**,
why do I get **FALSE** results?

Is there a way to find out the values ​​of 4 cells are the same or different?

[image]

Comment: `=AND(A1=A2,A2=A3,A3=A4)`

Comment: Formulas > Evaluate Formula to see what's *actually* happening.

Comment: If you go to the 'Formulas' tab and 'Evaluate Formula" on A5, you'll see the reason. Spoiler alert:  A1=A2 is evaluated first (and resolves to True)  then it True is evaluated with the value in A3 (which is 1). That's why the formula result is False.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1)=4`

Comment: `=COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:A4)) = 1`

Comment: Thank you all, now I understand, the third cell will be compared to TRUE .... :)

Comment: @Mabaega I hope the example below is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are using is these numbers you could check for the standard deviation. If it's `0` then all values are equal:

```
=STDEV.P(A1:A4)
```

So a check for equality could look like:

```
=IF(STDEV.P(A1:A4),"Different","Equal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF`.

### This is how it works in this example:

The COUNTIF returns a count of any cells that do not contain "1" which is compared to zero. If the count is zero, the formula returns TRUE. If the count is anything but zero, the formula returns FALSE.

You can apply that to any value you want to compare. Just place it before the `"<>"` in the formula.

This also works for "strings".

[image]

Comment: Or `=COUNTIF(A1:A4,"<>"&A1)=0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the range with the first cell, include it in the `AND` function and enter it as an array formula.

It will process both text and numeric values.

```
=AND(A1:A4=A1)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]